# get count of users having at least one transaction made within 7 days from the previous transaction

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to get the count of users who made at least one transaction that was made within 7 days from the previous transaction

What I've tried so far is:

```
WITH criteria_1 AS (
  SELECT
    fullvisitorid,
    COUNT(hits.TRANSACTION.transactionid) AS number_of_transactions
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`,
    UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  GROUP BY
    fullvisitorid
  HAVING
    COUNT( hits.TRANSACTION.transactionid) > 1
  ORDER BY
    2 DESC)
    
    
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS number_of_users_matching_crit1
FROM
  criteria_1
```

But I feel like I'm missing something here, how this could be improved?

Comment: Hi Saul, If you have transaction timestamp then you can write a query using lag function to find the timestamp of previous transaction and then return the users for whom difference between current and lag timestamp is less than 7.. I can help you with query if you can share table structure once.

Comment: @HimanshuAgrawal the table structure is publicly available in bigquery since it's a public table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the implementation of @HimanshuAgrawal's comment on comparing current and lag timestamp to get the transaction made within 7 days from the previous transaction. In this query I used a wildcard on the table (ga_sessions_20170*) to get data on multiple dates.

```
WITH
  criteria_1 AS (
  SELECT
    fullvisitorid as visitor_id,
    hits.TRANSACTION.transactionid as transaction_id,
    date as visit_date,
    LAG(date) OVER (PARTITION BY fullvisitorid ORDER BY date ASC) AS preceding_date
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170*` AS outside,
    UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  WHERE
    hits.TRANSACTION.transactionid IS NOT NULL)

SELECT
  visitor_id,
  transaction_id,
  visit_date ,
  preceding_date
FROM
  criteria_1
where preceding_date is not null
and visit_date != preceding_date
and safe.date_diff(cast(visit_date as date format 'YYYYMMDD')
    , cast(preceding_date as date format 'YYYYMMDD'), DAY) <= 7
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, it works like a charm